# Can I restore a content of the clipboard after restart?

Tags: xorg, clipboard

I have copied an important piece of some text into a clipboard from an external memory card. Occasionally, I have forgotten to paste this info into a local file and I have then switched the system off. Can I restore a content of the clipboard after system restart?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the clipboard manager [Pastie](https://launchpad.net/~hel-sheep/+archive/pastie), your pastes will survive a reboot, allowing you to choose the paste from a menu, and recover the data.

You can add pastie by doing this :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hel-sheep/pastie
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pastie
```

Then hit ALT-F2, and run `pastie`

Answer (score 1):

I am using klipper to manage the clipboard. Very handy tool. It has many feature including this(Can restore the clipboard contents after restart).

I don't think it is possible in default clipboard.